# How to exclude source files from cmake created visual studio projects based on target architecture?

Tags: visual-studio, build, 64-bit, cmake, 32-bit

I have a Windows Driver Kit solution that builds the dll for a printer driver.  I then convert the binary to C-code and include it into my source so that the dll can be extracted at run time and I don't have to distribute two files, just the .exe.

However, I have to build the dll for i386 and amd64 resulting in two dlls, and thus two c files to include.  I can check at compile time for which file to include, but we are generating our Visual Studio projects using cmake, and I'd like to include the correct c file in the project, and exclude the other.  This will allow the rebuild to work, will prevent duplicated symbols, etc.

We create the visual studio project by running cmake for either "Visual Studio 9 2008" or "Visual Studio 9 2008 Win64".  It doesn't seem possible to create a Visual Studio project for both architectures, so I could simply parse "CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=Visual Studio 9 2008" and add to my cmakelists.txt file the appropriate check.

Here is the cmakelists.txt file for the subproject in question

```
if(WIN32)
project (StaticDriverLib)

file(GLOB DriverLib_CPP *.cpp ../MasterInstallDir/*.cpp ../MasterInstallDir/amd64/*.cpp ../MasterInstallDir/i386/*.cpp)
file(GLOB DriverLibLib_H *.hpp *.h ../MasterInstallDir/*.hpp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../MasterInstallDir)

# static DriverLibLib library
add_library(StaticDriverLibLib ${DriverLib_CPP} ${DriverLib_H})
add_dependencies(StaticDriverLib StaticLibCore)
target_link_libraries(StaticDriverLib StaticCore Version.lib Setupapi.lib kernel32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib)

endif(WIN32)
```

As you can see, there is an i386 and an amd64 directory containing the architecture specific encoded binaries.  How do I tweak the cmakelists.txt so that one or the other is excluded based on the target generator?  For 64 bit we support VS2008 and soon VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your presumption is correct you need to check if you are compiling with 64bit support, and change the file glob directory based on that. The CMake variable CMAKE_CL_64 will be true / set if you are using the 64 windows compiler.